# Data binding from variable in fragment, android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a string variable in my fragment which I want to use in XML with data binding
This is my fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

var struc: String = "Organization Structure"

lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.getRoot()
}}
```

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="data"
        type="com.mountmeru.view.HomeFragment" />
</data>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.HomeFragment">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOrganization"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivOrganization"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{data.struc}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/mountmerured"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</FrameLayout></layout>
```

When I run the application the textview text is never set.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First way :

> This not direct way which you asked. But you can also do using data class, this is little bit long way but you can add multiple data.

1. Make data class

   ```
   data class Data(var struc: String = "Organization Structure")
   ```
2. Add this in xml

   ```
   <data>
       <variable
           name="dataModel"
           type="Data" />  // here data class path of step1
   </data> 

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".view.HomeFragment">
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
           android:id="@+id/tvOrganization"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/ivOrganization"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="@{dataModel.struc}"            // use like this
           android:textAlignment="center"
           android:textColor="@color/mountmerured"
           android:textSize="15sp" />
   </FrameLayout></layout>
   ```
3. In Activity or fragment

   ```
   private fun setData() {
       val data = Data(struc= "Organization")
       bindObject.dataModel = data
   }
   ```

## Second way :

### Or Else direct way is

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="struc"
        type="String" />  
</data>
```

and from activity/fragment

```
bindObject.struc = "Organization Structure";
```

## Third way :

### Or In your case you need to do this in onCreateView and everything works

```
binding.data = this;
```

Comment: This approach I know, I am looking for variable to direct communicate from the activity / fragment.

Comment: @WISHY : Check last line in my answer, it works I checked. As you want, use variable from xml

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mistaken while the layout inflating. Please try below code

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)
    return binding.getRoot()
}}
```

Comment: Both can be used for binding in fragment

Comment: Can you share full layout here